# Parse XML for using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xml

I receive a xml file like that:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<show name="test">
    <primary val="Hello">
        <secondary prop="Wolrd"/>
    </primary>
</show>
```

I would like to print "Hello" in my rails appliacaiton and when the user right click on a primary word (Hello) it replace it by the secondary word (Wolrd).

I found a way to do that by converting the xml in Html. But for several reason i would prefere to keep my xml file. And the convertion is a little bit too long.

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the XML DOM tree in the exactly same way as regular HTML.

Use `document.getElementsByTagName('')` and you can filter with `SELECTED_DOM_ELEMENT.hasAttribute('ATTRIBUTE_NAME')`

You can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_examples.asp

Comment: Thank you. I ll look at it. It seems to fit with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `gem "xml-simple"` [simple-gem](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: Ty. I already use Nokogiri. But I don't find the way to use it for my problem.
But I ll have a look at simple-gem.